# Android Retrofit read response if key not string

Tags: java, android, retrofit, kotlin

I have a retrofit response like this:

```
langs: {
   af: "Afrikaans",
   am: "Amharic",
   ar: "Arabic",
   az: "Azerbaijani",
   ba: "Bashkir", 
...
```

I tried to read it to `List<Map<String,String>>`but it not works.
Have anyone idea what is the best way to convert this json to object?

Call:

```
val result = RestAPI.instance.retrofit?.create(TranslateService::class.java)
    val call = result?.getLangs("en")
    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<LangsResponse>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LangsResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LangsResponse>?, response: Response<LangsResponse>?) {

        }

    })


data class LangsResponse(val dirs: List<String>,val langs: List<Map<String,String>>)
```

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Comment: I added my code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`langs` is a JSON object, so it can be read as a `Map<String,String>`. If it was an array of objects (`[{..},{..}]`) it would be `List<Map<String,String>>`.

Simply adjust the type and it should read properly.

Comment: Oh, Really. Thank you! :)